# How to get parent post fields in child pages? WP Types

Tags: php, wordpress

I made two custom post types with WP types plugin

1. Property (child)
2. Agent (Parent)

In Agent(Parent), i have created custom post fields with WP types Plugin:

1. Email
2. Phone
3. Fax No.

Now I want to show the fields in Property(Child) Posts.

I am using this code in single-property.php.

```
$parent_id = wpcf_pr_post_get_belongs($post->ID, 'agent');
$parent = get_post($parent_id);

$agentPhoto = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($parent->ID), 'agentPhoto');

//successfully get the parent photo
<img src="<?php echo $agentPhoto[0];?>" alt="<?php echo $parent->post_title;?>">

//successfully get the title of the parent
<?php echo $parent->post_title;?>
```

I am able to get the Title and Featured Image of Agent(Parent) but I can't get the custom fields which is (1. EMail, 2. Phone, and 3. Fax No.).
Below is the code for custom field through which i can get the fields but only in assign post types which is Agent(Parent).

```
$agentPhone = types_render_field( "agent-phone" );
$agentEmail = types_render_field( "agent-email" );
$agentFax   = types_render_field( "agent-fax" );
```

Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Don't use plugins to manipulate tables in database... Take a look at your database, there should be relations between Parent and Child, sometimes it's better to use SQL relations then object relations... 

I'd like to help you, but the code snippet you wrote, gives no clues on the problem... Perhaps the id of child element is not associated with parent...

Comment: @TheBumpaster Thanks for the reply, just edited my question above, maybe my question is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use this sortcode to get value of agentPhone , email etc...:and in place of id pass the parent post id:
<?php echo(do_shortcode('[types field="adresse" id="746" arg1="val1" arg2="val2"]')); ?>
<?php echo(do_shortcode('[types field="agent-email" id="746" arg1="val1" arg2="val2"]')); ?>
<?php echo(do_shortcode('[types field="agent-fax" id="746" arg1="val1" arg2="val2"]')); ?>
```

Comment: you are a hero Bro. I spent 2 days searching it without any luck. Thank you.